# replacing matrix of indices with corresponding vector with armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have an arma::umat matrix containing indices corresponding to an arma::vec vector containing either 1 or -1:

```
arma::umat A = { {8,9,7,10,6}, {5,3,1,2,4}};
arma::vec v = {-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1 ,1};
```

I would like to replace each element in the matrix with the corresponding value in the vector, so the output look like this:

```
A = {{-1,-1,1,1,-1},{-1,1,-1,1,1,1}}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: `arma::umat` is for unsigned. Thus you will have to create a different matrix (`arma::mat`) to hold the values. Also, remember that indexing starts at 0. Therefore, for you `v` vector with 10 elements the indexes must be in the closed interval [0, 9].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the result into `A` is not an option, since `A` contains unsigned integers, and your `v` vector has doubles. Just create an `arma::mat` to contain the result and loop for each row to index `v` accordingly. One way to do this is using [`.each_row`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow) member.

```cpp
#include <armadillo>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    arma::umat A = {{7, 8, 6, 9, 5}, {4, 2, 0, 1, 3}};
    arma::vec v  = {-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1};

    arma::mat result(A.n_rows, A.n_cols);

    auto lineIdx = 0u;
    // We capture everything by reference and increase the line index after usage.
    // The `.st()` is necessary because the result of indexing `v` is
    // a "column vector" and we need a "row vector".
    A.each_row([&](auto row) { result.row(lineIdx++) = v(row).st(); });

    result.print("result");

    return 0;
}
```

This code prints

```
result
  -1.0000  -1.0000   1.0000   1.0000  -1.0000
  -1.0000   1.0000  -1.0000   1.0000   1.0000
```